# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, windows, visual-studio-code, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to MariaDB database with PHP using 'PHP Server' extension in VScode, but it keeps giving me this error.

I can connect to database manually without any problems.

So far I have tried:

1. uncommenting 'extension_dir = "ext"' and 'extension=mysqli' in
   php.ini.production and php.ini.development files
2. putting 'php_mysqli.dll' in php, php/ext, system32, sys64WOW folders
   (Saw this solution on another forum)
3. reinstalling PHP and VS code

The code looks like this

```
define('DB_SERVER', '10.147.19.125');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_NAME', 'serwer');

echo "Connecting to database..";
/* Attempt to connect with database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Output of :
[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8BHh.png)

Comment: You're probably [not modifying the correct php.ini file](https://github.com/brapifra/vscode-phpserver/issues/47).

Comment: At the command line, run: `php --ini` ... and ensure that the php.ini file in the output is the correct one that was modified. Also, ensure to restart the webserver after making _any_ ini file changes.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after you made the changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Turns out that VS code was looking for ini file in C:/windows so i just copied php.ini.development file there and changed it's name. Works fine now.